# Brackets of start method not connecting in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

For some reason the `{` doesn't connect with the last one, if I put any code between the brackets of the void start method.

The first bracket connects to the lower bracket of void start everytime that I put something in void start. Deleting and writing it again doesn't seem to work.

[image]

```
public class move_windscreen_wiper : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        public float speed = 5.0f;
        private float rot = 0.0f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rot -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, rot, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Start you declare two *local* variables, they don't exist outside that method. Plus, shouldn't those methods be "public"?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, and no ;) They are not only local variables but they are not even alowed to have access modifiers. The methods can be private .. these are Unity specific "messages" and called by the Framework itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have access modifiers for local variables within a method.

You probably rather wanted to have two class level fields:

```
public class move_windscreen_wiper : MonoBehaviour
{
    // No need to do these in Start you can already initialize them directly
    // Additionally this one is now configurable via the Inspector
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    // This one will have the default value 0.0 anyway
    private float rot;

    private void Update()
    {
        rot -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, rot, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare variables as `public` and `private` inside of your method.
You likely want to pull those variables out to the class level. At that point you can access them from either method.

Comment: The true issue for the OP, but Hans is correct as well after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables must be declared outside the **Start** function, but you can continue modifying their values, like this:

```
public class move_windscreen_wiper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private float rot;

    void Start()
    {
        speed = 5.0f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rot -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, rot, 0.0f);
    }
}
```